# Spawning random image

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I got few images. I want to ask, how to spawn random one (as a sprite) offscreen? (red color on image shows, where can be image spawned) Thanks for answers.

Image: http://postimg.org/image/4vjo6rxgl/

Comment: Have you tried anything? Looked at SpritKit tutorials? Even opened XCode? Tons of resources out there.

Comment: Ye, but problem is in different screen resolutions - iPad retina and iPhone 4s...if I set up random position for iPad, problem will be delay on iPhone devices.. I don't know, how to explain...here is gif of final product: http://makeagif.com/aelNrC

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far. Are you hard-coding locations? Regardless of device you can reference `view.frame` for the screen and create the sprite at a location outside of it. No need to worry about resolution.